# Cannot use instance member within property initializer

Tags: ios, swift3

I have written a custom `UIView` and I found a strange problem. I think this is related to a very fundamental concept but I just do not understand it, sigh.....

```
class ArrowView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let arrowPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPathWithArrowFromPoint(startPoint: CGPoint(x:bounds.size.width/2,y:bounds.size.height/3), endPoint: CGPoint(x:bounds.size.width/2, y:bounds.size.height/3*2), tailWidth: 8, headWidth: 24, headLength: 18)

        let fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.00, green: 0.59, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        fillColor.setFill()
        arrowPath.fill()
    }
}
```

this code works fine but if I have grabbed this line out of the override draw function it does not compile. The error says I can not use the bounds property.

```
let arrowPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPathWithArrowFromPoint(startPoint: CGPoint(x:bounds.size.width/2,y:bounds.size.height/3), endPoint: CGPoint(x:bounds.size.width/2, y:bounds.size.height/3*2), tailWidth: 8, headWidth: 24, headLength: 18)
```

> Cannot use instance member 'bounds' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

I don not understand why I cannot use this bounds out of the func draw

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Cannot use instance member within property initializer - Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40710909/error-cannot-use-instance-member-within-property-initializer-swift-3)

Comment: you can fix this issue by using computed property [Example of Computed Property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39986404/6689101)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

So if we decode the error message you can figure out whats wrong. It says `property initializers run before self is available` so we need to adjust what we're doing since our property depends on bounds which belongs to self. Lets try a lazy variable. You can't use bounds in a let because it doesn't exist when that property is created because it belongs to self. So at init self isn't complete yet. But if you use a lazy var, then self and its property bounds will be ready by the time you need it.

```
lazy var arrowPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPathWithArrowFromPoint(startPoint: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width/2,y: self.bounds.size.height/3), endPoint: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width/2, y: self.bounds.size.height/3*2), tailWidth: 8, headWidth: 24, headLength: 18)
```

Comment: how it affect on behaviour of arrowPath? I mean whats going on to the project after changing let to lazey var?

Comment: lazy var means that this property is null until its accessed for the first time. Critically here that means that `self.bounds` is available because this property cannot be accessed until after `self` is initialized.