# Xcode 9 with Swift 4 Extra argument in call

Tags: ios11, xcode9, swift4, rx-swift

I was using **XCode 8.3** with **swift 3.1** and I updated to **Xcode 9** with **swift 4**, now in some classes when I use ***RXSwift***, I have this error compiler logs:

```
class petViewModel {
    var lastPetID: Int = 0
    var refreshing = Variable<Bool>(false)
    var vaccines: Results<vaccines>? = nil
    let error = Variable<(Int,String)>(0,"") // Extra argument in call
    let changes = Variable<([Int], [Int], [Int])>([Int](), [Int](), [Int]())  // Extra argument in call
    var firstLoad = Variable<Bool>(false)

    // and more code bla bla bla

}
```

using ***RXSwift*** what is the best way to implement it? before was compiling me without any problem, any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
let change1 = Variable<[Int]>([Int]())
let change2 = Variable<[Int]>([Int]())
let change3 = Variable<[Int]>([Int]())

let changes = Observable.combineLatest(change1.asObservable(), change2.asObservable(), change3.asObservable())
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @Vini App, but now is show me a compiler error: "Cannot use instance member 'change1' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45423321/cannot-use-instance-member-within-property-initializer

Answer (score 0):

I received a user @biboran response in [GitHub](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1473), and
the issue is that swift 4.0 currently doesn't support tuple transformations.

my Variable is not compiling because I declared it as a tuple and pass it as a variadic parameter. Just wrap it into a tuple:

```
let changes = Variable<([Int], [Int], [Int])>(
  ( // <-- this is a tuple I'm missing
    [Int](), 
    [Int](), 
    [Int]()
  ) // <-- this is a tuple I'm missing
)
```

as for my combineLatest, I have to wrap the argument into a collection (using a literal for example)

```
Observable.combineLatest([
  change1.asObservable(), 
  change2.asObservable(), 
  change3.asObservable()
])
```