# difference between two types of variable declarations?

Tags: swift

I have doubts about where I should use this declaration:
`var name: String = 'Name'`
and
`var name: String = {return 'Name'}`

I saw this in some codes where I work, and I would like to know the difference between these statements

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What makes a property a computed property in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39986129/what-makes-a-property-a-computed-property-in-swift). If you have questions like this I would recommend reading [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) book, it's a very good resource for both new and experienced swift programmers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: One is a function, one is a `String`

`var name: String = "Name"` is a "regular" variable assignment. You create a `var` of type String with the identifier `name` and assign it the value "Name".

`var name: String = {return "Name"}` won't compile. You're creating a `var` of type String but then instead of assigning it a string you're assigning it a function. The curly braces indicate a function.

So...

```
var name = "Name"
print(name)
```

1. Creates a variable `name` with the value name.
2. Prints the value of variable name [expected output `Name`]

Whereas

```
var name = {return "Name"}
print(name)
```

1. Creates a variable `name` with the value of `{return "Name"}`
2. Prints that to the console [expected output `(Function)`]

However

```
var name = {return "Name"}
print(name())
```

1. Creates a variable `name` with the value of `{return "Name"}`
2. Evaluates that function and prints the result [expected output `Name`]

Therefore

```
var sum = {return 1+2}
print(sum())
```

1. Creates a variable `sum` with the value of `{return 1+2}`
2. Evaluates that function and prints the result [expected output 3]

One last note-- you used single quotes (`'`) but you should declare strings with double quotes (`"`).

Answer (score 0):

The first one is stored property.
The second one is computed property.

The difference here is, the code in { } of computed property is execute each time you access it. It has no memory to store the value by itself.

For example, if your viewController has a property:

```
var label: UILabel { return UILabel() }

// Then you use it as

label.text = "hello"   // label 1
label.textColor = .red // another label, label 2

// the label 1 and label 2 are different, it's initialized each time use access it.
```